# Using string in different class

Tags: objective-c

I have a simple question about passing parameters between classes.

I have a `UITextField` in class A, which is filled with a `NSString` - *"stringA"*
I want to use that string in a different class, class B.
But, I want to set that text (from that string) in a `UITextField` on class B, as soon as I press the button to change from viewA to viewB.
How do I manage that? I just don't get it.

#### Edit:

#### ViewA.h

```
@interface StaedteViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate> {


IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
}


@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *textField1;

-(IBAction)staedtebestaetigen:(id)sender;

@end
```

#### ViewA.m

```
@implementation StaedteViewController

@synthesize picker, textField1;


- (IBAction)staedtebestaetigen:(id)sender {

    PreiseingabeViewController *PreiseingabeView = [[[PreiseingabeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    PreiseingabeView.textField1.text = textField1.text;

    [self presentModalViewController:PreiseingabeView animated:YES];
}   

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    self.textField1.text = @"SomeText";

}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.textField1 = nil;

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [textField1 release];

    [super dealloc];

}
```

#### ViewB.h

```
@interface PreiseingabeViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
    NSString *text;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *textField1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@end
```

#### ViewB.m

```
@synthesize textField1;


- (NSString *)text {
    return self.textField1.text;
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)value {
    textField1.text = value;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.textField1 = nil;
```

I set up the textfield via IB

Comment: @Enrico Campidoglio -> OS X doesn't know UITextField

Comment: @Mats Stijlaart the question has been updated with the right class name since I've posted my comment. Before that it just said _"text field"_ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make a UIViewController which contains both views. Link the action to the controller and when the action is fired, get the value of the first textfield and put it into the second text field.